# KeyError: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'> when saving dataframe to excel

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Good Morning, 
I have been using python for about a year and a half and I find myself in front of a basic issue that I can't get to solve.

I have a simple dataframe (df), not big (about 12k lines and 10 columns) that includes one column that is "datetime64[ns]" format, one "float64" and all others are "object". *I debugged and can say that the error comes from the datetime column.*

When I save this df to Excel, I get the following message:

> File "test.py", line 16, in 
>       test.to_excel(writer,'test')   File "C:\Users\renaud.viot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 1766, in to_excel
>       engine=engine)   File "C:\Users\renaud.viot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py",
>   line 652, in write
>       freeze_panes=freeze_panes)   File "C:\Users\renaud.viot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py",
>   line 1395, in write_cells
>       xcell.value, fmt = self._value_with_fmt(cell.val)   File "C:\Users\renaud.viot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py",
>   line 291, in value
>       self._bind_value(value)   File "C:\Users\renaud.viot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py",
>   line 193, in _bind_value
>       self._set_time_format(value)   File "C:\Users\renaud.viot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py",
>   line 277, in _set_time_format
>       self.number_format = fmts[type(value)] 
>   KeyError:

The piece of code I am using is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from pandas import ExcelWriter

test = pd.read_excel("test_in.xlsx")
test["CaseDate"] = pd.to_datetime(test["CaseDate"])
writer = ExcelWriter("test_out.xlsx")
test.to_excel(writer,'test')
writer.save()
```

Please see below the sample of the data:

```
>    A   CaseDate 
> 0  A 2018-08-30 
> 1  A 2018-08-30 
> 2  A 2018-08-30 
> 3  A 2018-08-30 
> 4  A 2018-08-30 
> 5  A 2018-08-30 
> 6  A 2018-08-30 
> 7  A 2018-08-30 
> 8  A 2018-08-30 
> 9  A 2018-08-30
```

There must be something obvious...
Thank you for your help.
BR,
Renaud

Comment: You cannot see the last piece of error for some reason:
> KeyError: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>.                          Also, the data I tried to present above is a 2 column df with one having only A and being called "A" and one with dates and being called "CaseDate"

Comment: Just tested and couldn't reproduce... but I did just `test.to_excel('test_out.xlsx', 'test')`

Comment: Thank you Rafael - I still have the same error. KeyError: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>

Comment: @RafaelC: Could you please tell me that class of any of your element in the column "CaseDate"? <br/> I used <code> print(type(test["CaseDate"][0]).__name__) </code> . <br/> I get the following: "Timestamp".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having the same problem in my project. I couldn't understand why this error is happening but I found a solution.

I believe this error is related to the module `openpyxl`. It is used by Pandas as an engine to export the data as an excel file. As you are naming the file with a `.xlsx` extension, automatically the class `ExcelWritter` uses `openpyxl` as the default engine.

What I've done is to change this engine. You can pass a parameter to `ExcelWritter` calling a new engine (`xlsxwriter`) to export the dataframe.

So my code changed from:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, 'data')
writer.save()
```

to this one:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='data')
writer.save()
```

If you don't have the module `xlsxwriter` installed in your environment, just use `pip install xlsxwriter` and after that execute your code.

That should solve your problem too.

Comment: Hi Arnold - thank you. It does work for me as well. It is weird and seem odd to me. I rerun using the "normal" way with another login in the same environment and it worked... I am confused but thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi @rvaux, I'm using Pipenv to control my environment and also have a Anaconda Python interpreter. I came across this problem in my environment and when I tried to run the same project using the Anaconda interpreter everything worked well. That's why I realized the problem was with sub packages required to run the Openpyxl. When I use pipenv install openpyxl, the mais module are installed, but something is missing. So I tried xlsxwriter and everything was ok. I did he same as you, rollback my script to openpyxl and it stated to work correctly, because of some subpakage necessary was installed.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with pandas 0.23.4 and openpyxl 2.5.6. I updated (using conda update openpyxl) to 2.5.8 and the problem went away.

Comment: Went away for me after updating pandas from 0.19.2 to 0.24.2 (the latest version of openpyxl was already installed).